# Disable bridge forwarding in raw socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I create a raw socket to receive and forward on my machine which has two interfaces(eth0, eth1) bridged together.

```
socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, 0xabcd);
```

My protocol will send some broadcast packets and I would like forward it on my own.

How to disable forwarding my specific packets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After weeks of working, I modified my nic driver and forward specific packet to user land via netlink.
Specific packets were dropped after be forwarded, so bridge will not forward these packets for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use iptables / ebtables to stop the forwarding over the bridge and use libpcap in your program to pick up the packets/frames you would like to forward with your program.  It might be kind of hackish, but libpcap can deliver just the packets you want to listen to, regardless of the machines firewall/bridge forwarding rules.

There are also some iptables targets that will deliver matched packets to userspace.  You might be able to use those to deliver and drop them in the kernel, leaving it up to your application to retransmit them.